# Plotting a histogram with the column names as the x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I would like to take a dataframe, and produce a histogram with the column names as the x-axis and the count as the y-axis

Dataset:

```
sess    lea opps
  0      0    0
  1      1    0
  0      0    0
  0      0    0
  0      0    0
  0      0    0
  1      1    0
  0      0    0
  0      0    0
  0      0    0
```

Comment: sess is the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline #only jupyter notebooks
```

then you can use 
**to show the sum:**

```
df.sum().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

to show the count of zeros and ones:

```
count=pd.concat([df.sum().rename('count_1'),df.eq(0).sum().rename('count_0')],axis=1)
print(count)
count.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
```

Output:

```
      count_1  count_0
sess        2        8
lea         2        8
opps        0       10
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

counts = df.sum()
x, y = counts.index, counts.values
plt.bar(x, y)
```

You should get something like this:

[image]

Comment: You can show the figure from the DataFrame, it is not necessary to create additional variables. Check my answer